# What does this mean? java

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner("Berries are red");
sc.skip("...");//what does this mean?
System.out.print(sc.next);
```

What does ... Mean? This was showed to us in a computer science class but never explained.

Comment: You should read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String))

Comment: Have you tried running the code above to see what the results are? If you check it out on [ideone](http://ideone.com/MDLFNF) you can see the output is `"ries"` so what do you think that line means?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)) it skips a certain input. In this specific case it skips three characters, because the regex pattern "..." matches three (any) characters. In a more generic case it only skips if the pattern matches, so if you would for example have `sc.skip('\d')` it would only skip the next digit (if it matches)

Answer (score 0):

It means it skips "...".

`public Scanner skip (Pattern pattern)` takes as argument a pattern to ignore.

Next time try it / google it before you ask a question.